# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'D:\gmail-react\src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database

I am installed firebase logged in as well.

I am getting a completely white screen on importing it.

This is the firebase.js file

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBb9O35r_N--vwBZNfpxY3vZHzi4wH1oII",
    authDomain: "fir-237a1.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: " fir-237a1",
    storageBucket: "fir-237a1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1055799909510",
    appId: "1:1055799909510:web:c90fad7d5113500585c507"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

This is where I am importing firebase, SendMail.js file

```
import { db } from "./firebase.js"
import firebase from 'firebase';

function SendMail() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onSubmit = (formData) => {
        console.log(formData);
        db.collection('emails').add({
            to: formData.to,
            subject: formData.subject,
            message: formData.message,
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });

        dispatch(closeSendMessage());
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are one by another the import here:

```js
import { db } from "./firebase.js"
```

Should be like this:

```js
import { db } from "/firebase.js"
```

without the ".". If you use the "." the file will be searched in the folder above and that is how it looks like. It wen to the `src` folder witch is probable above the one where your file is.

Also update your `firebase.js` file to this:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBb9O35r_N--vwBZNfpxY3vZHzi4wH1oII",
  authDomain: "fir-237a1.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: " fir-237a1",
  storageBucket: "fir-237a1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1055799909510",
  appId: "1:1055799909510:web:c90fad7d5113500585c507",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

and make sure you use the latest Firebase JS SDK Version 9.x

A just saw that a lot of your code has the old SKD 8 in the repo. You can either stay with that syntax by using the `compad` version in the new SDK or refactor your code to use the new syntax of SDK version 9. Here is a [migration guid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

You need to pick one of those two options. I would recommend to migrate to the new version.

With the new SDK version you don't even need the `firebase.js` file. Your code would look like this:

```js
import { getFirestore, addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

function SendMail() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = (formData) => {
    console.log(formData);
    addDoc(collection(db, "emails"), {
      to: formData.to,
      subject: formData.subject,
      message: formData.message,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  };

  dispatch(closeSendMessage());
}
```

Comment: This didn't work it is still showing the same error

Comment: Can you pls share a screenshot of your folder and file structure.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the folder structure https://photos.app.goo.gl/WPCaEwLvhkHpwDg58                                                            I believe that the error is not coming from the import db line it is coming from the second one the import firebase from 'firebase' one because when I commented out this line line the error went off  Here is my Source Code you can check this out as well https://github.com/aadipoddar/Gmail-React

Comment: I have updated the answer. You problem is that you use the old syntax but have the new Firebase SDK version 9 installed. More details about it in the answer.